# How to debug the MySQL error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I understand that this question has been asked multiple times but I am huge beginner, I am transferring the database from SQL workbench to phpmyadmin. I keep getting this error:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`staff` (
  `StaffID` TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(254) NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`),
  CONSTRAINT `StaffID`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ' at line 8
```

here is the actual SQL code:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 04/04/16 23:56:12
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ApplicationSystem
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema ApplicationSystem
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `ApplicationSystem` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ApplicationSystem`.`staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`staff` (
  `StaffID` TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(254) NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`),
  CONSTRAINT `StaffID`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` (
  `Type` ENUM('A', 'HA', 'AT') NULL,
  `ID` TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `ID_idx` (`ID` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`Applicants` (`ApplicantID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`staff` (`StaffID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ApplicationSystem`.`Applicants`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`Applicants` (
  `ApplicantID` TEXT(6) NULL,
  `Firstname` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `surname` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `DOB` DATE NULL,
  `Gender` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Postcode` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
  `ApplicantMobile` TEXT(11) NULL,
  `ApplicantHome` TEXT(11) NULL,
  `ApplicantEmail` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `ParentName` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `Relationtoapplicant` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `ParentEmail` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `ParentAddress` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `ParentPostcode` VARCHAR(9) NULL,
  `ParentHome` TEXT(11) NULL,
  `ParentMobile` TEXT(11) NULL,
  `Currentschool` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `ApplicantInYr11` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `Sibbling` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `SibblingName` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `SibblingYear` TEXT(2) NULL,
  `MedicalConditions` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `AccessArrangementsAvailable` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `AccessArrangments` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Ethnic` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `FirstLanguage` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `HomeLanguage` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `Religion` VARCHAR(15) NULL,
  `Nationality` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `ArmedForces` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `PreviouslyLookedAfter` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `EUResident` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `RestrictionResidence` ENUM('yes', 'no') NULL,
  `school1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `school2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `school3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `school4` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `UPN` TEXT(13) NULL,
  `UCL` TEXT(13) NULL,
  `ULN` TEXT(10) NULL,
  `Password` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `Course1` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Course2` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Course3` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Course4` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Course5` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  `Complete` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `Outcome` ENUM('R', 'A') NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ApplicantID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `idtable1_UNIQUE` (`ApplicantID` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ApplicantEmail_UNIQUE` (`ApplicantEmail` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicantID`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ApplicationSystem`.`table1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`table1` (
  `ID` TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
  `outcome` TEXT(6) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ApplicationSystem`.`outcome`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`outcome` (
  `ID` TEXT(6) NOT NULL,
  `Outcome` ENUM('R', 'A') NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ID`)
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`Applicants` (`ApplicantID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `ApplicationSystem` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Placeholder table for view `ApplicationSystem`.`view1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`view1` (`id` INT);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- View `ApplicationSystem`.`view1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ApplicationSystem`.`view1`;
USE `ApplicationSystem`;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS
```

Comment: neither mysql workbench nor phpmyadmin are databases engine and as such, you should not have to transfer the database anywhere, just recreate the connections.

Comment: on another note, this looks like a very simple syntax issue, easily solvable by glancing through http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Pro tip: users who set a username of `srhgrsdhfdh` appear to have bashed the keyboard in order to get quick help, and are generally assumed not to want to be members of the community. That can affect the kind of help you receive. Don't forget to read the Help Centre too, specifically on what kinds of question work best here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  CONSTRAINT `StaffID`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` ()
```

To declare a foreign key constraint, you have to indicate the specific columns which take part in the constraint. You have not done so here. The correct syntax is

```
  CONSTRAINT `StaffID`
    FOREIGN KEY (<name of a column in this table>)
    REFERENCES `ApplicationSystem`.`UserType` (<name of the matching column in the referenced table>)
```

filling in the `<placeholders>` with the correct actual column names.

Sebas has a good point, though; the data is not "in" either Workbench or phpMyAdmin; these are just administrative clients that connect to the database process, so you should be able to just set up a new connection to the existing database.

Comment: Thanks bro.  I am incredibly grateful. Turns out while using the visual database creation thing, I accidentally created 2 links for both tabled, each.

Answer (score 0):

```
FOREIGN KEY (`here shoud be the column name the key belongs to`)
```

Comment: Thanks bro.  I am incredibly grateful. Turns out while using the visual database creation thing, I accidentally created 2 links for both tabled, each.